# in how many ways can Sam form a band?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Sam needs $5$ different instruments for his band.He finds $5$ people,each of whom can play two instruments. If no two people can play the same two instruments and each instrument can be played by exactly two people,in how many ways can Sam form his band from the $5$ people.

Initially i thought that the answer was $2^5$ but then I realized that it couldn't be the answer as i was counting in some cases the same person for two instruments,which can't be true.

I've gone then by brute force  and calculated $6$ ways in which we can form a band ,but I am not really sure of the solution ...i think i am making some conceptual mistake...

So i am asking a more systematic approach for the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "no two people can play the same two instruments"?

Comment: no two people can play same instrument $A,B$

Comment: Do the $5$ people chosen need to cover the $5$ instruments?

Comment: @Nicholas yes ,you can't have 1 person playing two instruments. (it's a band how can you have one person playing two instruments at once ?)

Comment: But can the band have two of one instrument and zero of another.

Comment: Do you mean two persons playing the same instrument ?

Comment: Actually the problem says that each of these $5$ persons  can play one instrument of the others $4$,not that you can have two persons in the same instrument. (i.e. every person has in common one instrument of another person)

Comment: Sam can't form a band since he scared off all the talented guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way is to imagine the $5$ people arranged in a circle, so that each has a player adjacent on each side who can play her instrument, so

$AB-BC-CD-DE-EA[AB]$

Once the first player decides whether to play instrument A or instrument B, the entire distribution of instruments gets decided, hence only **2 ways**

Comment: What if ab-bc-ba and de-ed?  The are six ways in that case.

Comment: $b$ is playable by $3$ people, (but that could be a typo for $ab-bc-ca$). However,, $de-ed$ violates  "no two people can play the same two instruments"

Comment: That was a typo.  Yeah.  "no two people"... irritating cause I had this right first but I allowed myself to be talked out of it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you said I will use Ian Miller 1) answer.

> 1) Without loss of generality let Person A play instruments 1 & 2, Person B play 2 & 3, Person C play 3 & 4, Person D play 4 & 5 and Person E play 5 & 1.

I think that means you have only 2 ways to form your band:

A:1, B:2, C:3, D:4, E:5

A:2, B:3, C:4, D:5, E:1

Answer (score 0):

$\require{cancel}$
Based on the information there are $\cancel{\text{two}}$one possible list$\cancel{\text{s}}$ of musical skills in the group:

**1)** Without loss of generality let Person A play instruments 1 & 2, Person B play 2 & 3, Person C play 3 & 4, Person D play 4 & 5 and Person E play 5 & 1.

$\cancel{\text{**2)** Without loss of generality let Person A and Person B player 1 & 2. Let Person C play 3 & 4, Person D play 3 & 5, and Person E play 5 & 3.}}$

In the first case if we assign A to play 2 then B must play 3 and C must play 4 and so on. A similiar argument applies if A play 1. So this is two cases.

$\cancel{\text{In the second case we have similar arguments for the two separate rings of people (AB is separate to CDE) which gives four cases.}}$

So $\cancel{6}$2 cases total.

Comment: Can you elaborate part $2$?,what do you mean by "let person $A,B$ play instruments $1,2$ and person $C$ play $3,4$ ?I think persons $A$ and $B$ are sharing the same instruments,if i am understanding correctly.

Comment: I didn't read it correctly. I missed the bit saying no two people can play the same two instruments.

Comment: Why did you change this? Why can't person c play instrument 1 and 3, while person 4 and 5 play... oh.